# get-counter - cant connect to remote computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using Get-counter to get e.g. processor time. I can get it for local computer, but I don't know how to enter credentials to get data from remote computer. Or do I need something turn on on that server to provide that informations?

```
Get-Counter -ComputerName "remotecomputer" -counter "\Processsor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

Error message:

```
Get-Counter: Unable to access the desired computer or service. Check the permissions and authentication of the log service or the interactive user session against those on the computer or servece being monitored.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the credentials you're using on the local workstation are what will be used to access the remote system. So if you don't have administrative rights on the remote system, this will fail.

You can tell Powershell to prompt you for alternate credentials with many cmdlets by specifying `-credential (get-credential)`, but apparently `Get-Counter` isn't one of them.

`Get-Counter` doesn't use WinRM, so there shouldn't be anything additional required to enable on the server.

Comment: OK, i added my local account to Performance Monitor Users group on server and it's working now. It's sad that Get-Counter doesn't use credentials. Anyway, thank you!